# What is the best way to interpolate for all values of n, with two arrays in c?

Tags: c, arrays, header, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I want to interpolate for any value of n with the information of two arrays. I have a main file where omega and n are used throughout the code, and I have a header file for the interpolation. n and omega is declared in the main file as `int n = 129;` and `double omega;`. I have tried to interpolate mathematically like the code below, but it seems to get in trouble when n has a value that is different from a value in the array. It seems to work for like n=30, n=60, n=100 etc, but not for n=35, n=129 etc.

Is there any other way to interpolate in a better way? I am not very good with pointers, so im not sure if im using them right, or if they are needed at all..

I have tried to create a separate project for the interpolation without the header file and it seems to work okey, so I suspect it has something to with the header file but im not completely sure. I am using CodeBlocks.

```
#include "header.h"

void interpol(int n, double *omega){

int i;
int nn[9] = {0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 100, 500};
double oo[9] = {1.7, 1.78, 1.86, 1.92, 1.95, 1.96, 1.97, 1.98, 1.99};

    for (i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
       if (n<nn[i])
       {
           *omega = oo[i-1] + ((oo[i+1]-oo[i-1])/(nn[i+1]-nn[i-1]))*(n-nn[i-1]);
           break;
       }
    }
printf("\nomega = %lf \n", *omega);
}
```

I'll add a simplified version of the main file since the interpolation is in the very beginning and the rest is not important for this case. In the header it is:

`void interpol(int n, double *omega);`

main script:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){

int n;
double omega;

n=129;

interpol(n, &omega);
printf("\nomega = %lf \n", omega);

return 0;
}
```

For n=129 expected value should be 1.98 ish, but it comes out as 2.6 ish.

Comment: Please post all the code, including main. There's no way for us to tell what is going wrong with what you've got there. Also, if you suspect that something is going wrong with a header, copying and pasting it manually into the relevant file is one way of seeing if the value persists. You also talk about projects, which indicates that you're using an IDE of sorts and it would be helpful if you told us which.

Comment: How do you call function `interpol`?

Comment: @Heim Please include it in the main post, not as a comment here. If there is a lot of unrelated code, then making a new project where all of that is excised is a good way to test if it still works. Additionally, you only say that the code doesn't work like you want it to, but there's no way for us to know exactly what that means. What are the expected correct values, and what are the wrong values you get?

Comment: Why did you change `*omega = ...` to be `omega = ...`now. The former was correct. The latter is wrong.

Comment: @alk copied from the wrong code, corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in all likelyhood this bit:

```
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
   if (n < nn[i]) {
       omega = oo[i-1] + ((oo[i+1]-oo[i-1])/(nn[i+1]-nn[i-1]))*(n-nn[i-1]);
       break;
   }
}
```

Here you run the danger of reading out of bounds at either end. If at i = 0 then `oo[i - 1]` read outside at the start end and at i = 8 `oo[i + 1]` reads outside at the end.

Comment: What do you suggest as a solution then? I have tried to play around with some numbers but it still wont work :/

Comment: @Heim Well, if starting at i = 0 is too small of a starting value for i, and i < 9 lets i get too large, then maybe i should start at a slightly larger value and end at a slightly smaller one instead?

Comment: didnt fix the problem im affraid :/